# Nativescript - Error: more than one library with package name (Android)

Tags: nativescript

I'm getting the following error when I build under Android

Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

How can I fix this?

I understand this has to do with some incompatibility with Android sdk library - but I didn't update anything explicitly - are libs being auto updated in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tns-android version is 4+ then you can try with tns platform add android@3.4
It worked for me.