# NativeScript:more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

I tried to build the project in android using nativescript. It throw
    the error like this more than one library with package name
    `'com.google.android.gms.license'`.

**package.json**

```
  "tns-android": {
  "version": "3.3.1"
}

   "nativescript-onesignal": "^1.0.7",   
"nativescript-push-notifications": "0.0.19",
```

**App.gradle**

```
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'   
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'    
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'     
   compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0"
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' }
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.3.1"
    }

Comment: [See if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453806/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license)

Comment: You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417231/nativescript-error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-android/49463502#49463502) I have faced same issue.

Comment: I tried to update the android version like tns platform add android@3.4.But iam getting error during update like cp: no such file or directory: cd/Project/node_modules/tns-android/framework/libs

Comment: bifurcate sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove node_modules folder.

1.npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save
2.uinstall & update tns version/(npm install -g nativescript )
3.update node/npm
4.npm cache clean -f

By using this comments i resolved the issues

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules and hooks folders from project and platform.
re-install them "npm install" and then try "tns platform remove android"
"tns platform add android@3.4"